# Can I implement custom attributes similar to [FromBody] and [FromUri] when using ASP.NET Webforms (.NET 4.x)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET web forms application and would like to handle all web methods and explicitly tell them where to get their values from (`body` or `uri`). Is this achievable without using .NET Core or Web API?

I've tried creating a custom binder class that intercepts all web method requests and manually get the parameter values either from request `body` or `uri`, but this might posed performance issue too.

Based on my research so far, `[FromBody]` & `[FromUri]` aren't usable in webforms alone.

Maybe because they are not needed? But I'm not really familiar with how webforms work in this specific scenario.

Some of the materials that I've checked:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api

Comment: You can use both tags in a method

Comment: It will require additional reference/package, problem is I don't have the necessary refences and I can't add them in due to the system being old and can't take some risk adding some new packages/references in it.

Comment: you should have a version control system like GitHub

Comment: have you tried using Request.Form["param1"]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure of the goal here?

Why not pass information to that web method call then? You can pass as many "values" to the web method as json array, so I not grasping why you need anything more?

And it is not clear why you can't add any old custom attribute to any control you dropped into that page? Any attribute you add to a control can be used and seen by code behind. So, once again, I failing to see your goal here.

I mean, these days, do people EVEN by hand write code to fill out some data on a web page? (Really??????).

The so-called CRUD in which a page loads, and the controls filled out with some data should be done with a "general" routine that takes your say row of data and simple automatic fills out the controls for you (you folks don't hand code that stuff, do you?).

I mean, if I have 10 controls on a web page, and I want data to be placed into those controls, when we don't do this anymore:

```
 txtHotelName.text = MyDataObject.hotelName
 txtCity.text = MyDataOjbect.City
 etc. etc.
```

No one written the above type of code since the early PC software days, before projects like say MS-access or FoxPro or whatever came along and "automatic" did this kind of dirty work.

I mean, if you looking to bind some data to render that data into a web page?

Then just create a "general" code routine to pull data from "where ever" and then call a routine to put that data into the control(s) on that web page.

We can "make up" or add custom attributes for any control. So, let's use a "made up" attribute called "f". That will define what database column to load that control with.

I fail to see why one would consider some kind of binding method at the web page request level as oppose to just writing a routine to take some row of data, and put that data into the existing controls you dropped into that page?

Why all these strange hand-stands of code here then?

Let's make a simple example.

We will select a hotel from a combo box (drop down list), and then have the values displayed for the user to edit the one record. And we MOST CERTAINLY will not hand code the filling out of those controls, right?????

So, our markup will have 2 areas. The first area is the simple drop-down list.

The 2nd area is a div, and inside we have the control(s) dropped in that allows editing of that data.

So, we have this markup:

```
    <div id="PickHotel" runat="server">
        <h3>Select Hotel to Edit</h3>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboHotels_SelectedIndexChanged"
            width="240px"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>
```

So above let's us select a hotel.

And right below above, let's drop in a div with some simple controls to "edit" the one record.

Don't matter what we drop into that 2nd div, but say this:

```
<div id="EditRecord" runat="server" 
    style="float: left;padding: 15px;border:solid 2px black" visible="false">
    <h3>Edit Hotel</h3>
    <div style="float: left" class="iForm">
        <label>HotelName</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="280" f="HotelName" /><br />
        <label>First Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" Width="140"  f="FirstName"/><br />
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" Width="140" f="LastName" /><br />
        <label>City</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" Width="140" f="City" /><br />
        <label>Province</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" Width="75" f="Province" /><br />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px" class="iForm">
        <label>Description</label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine"
            Height="150px" f="Description"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" Text=" Active" runat="server" 
            TextAlign="Right" f="Active" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" Text=" Has Balcony" runat="server" 
            TextAlign="Right" f="Balcony"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <button id="cmdSave" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" type="button"
        onserverclick="cmdSave_ServerClick">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save</span>
    </button>

    <button id="cmdCancel" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left: 15px"
        type="button"
        onserverclick="cmdCancel_ServerClick" >
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left">Back/Cancel</span>
    </button>

    <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left: 15px"
        type="button"
        onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick"
        onclick="if (!confirm('Delete Record?')) {return false};">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span>
    </button>

 </div>
```

So, note what we have in above. Each text box (or check box) or whatever? I used a "made up" attribute called f.

So, now our code behind looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

        cboHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        cboHotels.DataBind();
        cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel");

    }
```

So, above on first page load sets up the ddl.

And with auto post-back, then when we select a hotel, then we can use a "general" and 100% re-usable routine that will work for ANY page, and ANY data we wish to display.

That code looks like this:

```
    protected void cboHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboHotels.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            string strSQL =
                @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID";

            int pk = Convert.ToInt32(cboHotels.SelectedItem.Value);
            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pk;
            DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            General.FLoader(EditRecord, dt.Rows[0]);
            PickHotel.Visible = false;
            EditRecord.Visible = true;
            ViewState["PK"] = pk;

        }
    }
```

So, we have a routine called Floader. We just pass it the "div" and the row of data.

So, the end result is this:

[image]

So, as above shows, we don't have to hand code the flow of data into the controls, nor do we have to hand code the save of data. We can use one simple set of routines, and

```
 Floader. - takes one row of data, fills out controls

 Fwriter  - takes div, sends back to one row
```

The Floader routine thus looks like this:

```
    public static void FLoader(HtmlGenericControl F, DataRow rst)
    {
        foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in F.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                TextBox ctlC = c as TextBox;
                if (ctlC.Attributes["f"] != null)
                    if (rst.Table.Columns.Contains(ctlC.Attributes["f"]))
                        ctlC.Text = (DBNull.Value.Equals(rst[ctlC.Attributes["f"]]) ? "" : rst[ctlC.Attributes["f"]].ToString());
            }
            else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                CheckBox ctlC = c as CheckBox;
                if (ctlC.Attributes["f"] != null)
                    if (rst.Table.Columns.Contains(ctlC.Attributes["f"]))
                        if (DBNull.Value.Equals(rst[ctlC.Attributes["f"]]))
                            ctlC.Checked = false;
                        else
                            ctlC.Checked = (bool)rst[ctlC.Attributes["f"]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, you can add "label" and more controls to the above loop.

and the Fwriter routine simple does the reverse of the above.

So, it looks like this:

```
    public static void FWriter(HtmlGenericControl F, int fPK, string strTable)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + strTable + " WHERE ID = " + fPK;
            DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                DataRow rst = rstData.Rows[0];

                // take web controls, put into table
                FWriterUpdate(F, rst);
                // write table back to database
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, since the PK value is from viewstate, then I did risk a SQL concatenation above. However, you certainly could use a parameter like I did to load the data.

However, note in above, we have a simple two-way binding system, and one that means you not hand coding the filling out, or hand code even the sending back to the database.

> Maybe because they are not needed?

Indeed! Those poor folks that hand code loading of controls? They are less productive than tools that appeared in our industry 20 years ago. The idea that in this day and age people are STILL hand coding the loading of controls? That's set developers back to the dark ages. There is ZERO reason to hand code the loading of controls on a given web page. A few small helper routines, and you quite much done for the next 10 years, and you never hand code loading of controls on a page again - just call your general routine "helper" that loads up the controls on a page for you, and you quite much done.

So, I can't say there is much "need" to try and add to each page some hidden field, or new part to the post-backs. You are better off in near all cases to build a "general" routine, and feed it the div, or even the page object in question. At that point, then such code has full use of the current page object, and that tends to be less work, and more flexible then attempting to add some header or form data to each post back, and then attempting to process with a custom http handler. So for, your "use case" does not provide any benefits I can see over using plain jane standard code to achieve your goals here.